# 2 way data binding error for a livedata variable with proper xml binding

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata

I have a loginViewModel for my login Activity, in activity_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="loginViewModel"
            type="com.example.test.ui.login.LoginViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mobile_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:editable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/mobile_number_string"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="@={loginViewModel.phoneNumber}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/otp_input"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

And in my loginViewModel i have defined my livedata as

```
class LoginViewModel : ViewModel(){
    private val _phoneNumber = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val phoneNumber : LiveData<String>
        get() = _phoneNumber
}
```

Now, while building I am getting the following error

```
The expression \u0027loginViewModelPhoneNumber.getValue()\u0027 cannot be inverted, so it cannot be used in a two-way binding\n\nDetails: There is no inverse for method getValue, you must add an @InverseMethod annotation to the method to indicate which method should be used when using it in two-way binding expressions
```

All articles that I am reading suggesting this way to implement.
Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: make your function return `MutableLiveData` since `LiveData`'s setValue() is private

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately for two-way data binding you need to use MutableLiveData.

You should remove private on `_phoneNumber`.

Then change xml to use it `android:text="@={loginViewModel._phoneNumber}"`.

Answer (score 2):

change from

```
private val _phoneNumber = MutableLiveData<String>()
```

to

```
public val _phoneNumber = MutableLiveData<String>()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are binding `phoneNumber` which is a LiveData that does not have any interface for writing value.

Consider removing `phoneNumber`, and using Kotlin-based approach, with just a public property

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with the code.

- you try to use `val phoneNumber` that is not mutable in two way binding, thus is has only getter so binding class can only read value from field, to receive data from the UI - binding class wants to use setter, but there is no setter present, thus the `phoneNumber` won't change.
- for the property that binds `phoneNumber` you try to use `LiveData` which is not mutable - you should use `MutableLiveData` in case you need it to be able to change.
- if you want to listen to the changes of `phoneNumber` you need to add `LiveData` `Observer` like

```
phoneNumber.observe{
  val value = it
}
```

Hope it helps.